# Exponential distribution with mean 1/lambda

Tags: exponential-distribution

[image: find variance of N] 
Let x1,x2,x3,.......xn be independent and identically distributed random variables from exponential distribution with mean 1/Lambda. Let Sn=x1+x2+......+xn and N=infimum(n>=1:Sn>1) then what is the variance of N.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, just a hint. Have a look at Erlang distribution which is a distribution of $S_n$. Then you need to find out how $n$ behaves, conditionally on $S_n>1$.

Comment: But Sn follows gamma distribution with parameter (n,Lambda) . Can we solve this problem using gamma distribution?

Comment: You are right - but in the case of gamma, $n$ can be _any real number_. But in your setup, $n$ can only be integer which is what is assumed by the Erlang distribution.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your help